# Can we find a closed form for this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Can we find a closed form for this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ix} x^{\alpha -1} \mathrm{d}x$$

I am assuming it requires complex analysis and the use of Cauchy's residue theorem, but is there any elementary way other than complex analysis to evaluate this? I am not asking for a solution; a hint or guidance would not be overlooked. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to type $z$ instead of $x$ in the exponential?

Comment: Just fixed it, thank you.

Comment: Maybe differentiate under the integral sign, i.e. Feynman's trick?

Comment: That's how I arrived here, but I cannot think of any parameter that would be useful. It resembles something like the gamma function but the imaginary number makes it more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(y)$ of
$$
f(x) = x^{\alpha-1}\mathbb{1}_{\{x\geq 0\}}
$$
evaluated at $y=1/(2\pi)$. If $\alpha\in(0,1)$ then
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{f}(y) &= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{(2i\pi y)^{\alpha}}
\end{align*}
$$
which implies
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}\,e^{-ix}\,\mathrm{d} x = i^{-\alpha}\,\Gamma(\alpha)
$$

---

Actually, another way of saying this is
$$
\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^{i\,\infty}z^{\alpha-1}e^{-z}\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
which is a formula I already saw somewhere (but I don't know where and how one proves it usually).

---

To prove the formula of the Fourier transform, one can first find the dependence in $y$ by a scaling argument and then use the fact that $\langle \hat{f}|\varphi\rangle = \langle f|\hat{\varphi}\rangle$ with $\varphi$ a Gaussian (for which we know the Fourier transform) to find the right constant.

Comment: The latter integral with i*infinity I saw as well but did not know what to do with it. The Fourier transform is perfect; thank you for your help!